# What is the most efficient way to dynamically add button controls to ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I've created a ASP.NET website and on page load I have to dynamically add button controls(80 to 500). When I add more than 40 buttons it takes a little bit of time for the page to load. So my question is: What is the best way to dynamically add button controls to ASP.NET web form without losing performance?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your relevant code please

Comment: The most efficient way is to forget about ASP.NET web controls and use JavaScript and HTML. Well, it is 2016, not 2006.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your design if you want to add that many button in your web page. But if you really need to, use javascript as Lex Li mentioned so it won't be stressful on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be Controls.Add(..). However, its likely rendering time here is your bottleneck - which is not strictly and ASP.net issue. Adding controls to an ASP.net control collection is super fast.

Albeit, 500 buttons on a given page seems excessive. You should probably look at a paging solution to get better performance.